# Complex Fourier series of $e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, fourier-series

I tried to calculate the complex Fourier series of $f(x)=e^{-x}~~(-1<x≤1),~~f(x+2)=f(x)$ but there's a point that I don't understand.

I calculated $C_n$ and formed like this
$$C_n=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1e^{-(1+in\pi)x}dx\\=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{e^{1+in\pi}}{1+in\pi}-\frac{e^{-(1+in\pi)}}{1+in\pi})$$
but the answer is $f(x)\sim \frac{e^2-1}{2e}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+in\pi}e^{in\pi x}$
I know I should apply $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ but how should I apply this and transform like this answer? I'm confused. Can someone tell me how to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $e^{in\pi}=e^{-in\pi}=(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the Fourier coefficient
$$
C_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{e^{1+in\pi}}{1+in\pi}-\frac{e^{-(1+in\pi)}}{1+in\pi}\right).
$$
Now $e^{\pm in\pi}=(e^{\pm i\pi})^n=(-1)^n$ and in general $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$, so in fact
$$
C_n
=
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n\frac{e-e^{-1}}{1+in\pi}
=
\frac{e^2-1}{2e}(-1)^n\frac{1}{1+in\pi}
.
$$
If you sum these up, you get exactly the formula you quote.

Comment: but how did you derive it? I don't understand well that $e^{1+in\pi}-e^{-(1+in\pi)}=(-1)^n(e-e^{-1})$. can you show me more ?

Comment: @hichewness It's the way the exponential of a sum works: $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$. The $a$ and $b$ are $\pm1$ and $\pm in\pi$.

Comment: I know, but you can't express $e^{1+in\pi}-e^{-(1+in\pi)}=e^{±(1+in\pi)}$can you?

Comment: @hichewness Indeed not. You have to simplify the two terms separately and combine them in the end.